# jquery get inner width returns different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get inner width of a div using jquery. The code I used to do so is as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("width : "+$("div").innerWidth());
}
```

But the code returns different values every time I refresh the page. Sometimes it returns 971 and sometimes it returns 1336,The actual width I have set to that particular division in CSS style sheet is 800px. Can anybody please tell me What's wrong in my code? and how can I get the right `innerwidth`?

Note: I need `innerwidth` to make a division responsive. I am displaying a chart in that division and I want my chart to be responsive.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try `window.onload` handler... Are you using `ajax` to update `div` contents ?

Comment: It's hard to figure the issue without HTML and corresponding CSS.

Comment: Ya Rayon. I am using ajax to update div contents.

Comment: so, your content might not yet be updated when you call on width. ready() is called when DOM is ready, not when ajax requests have completed

Comment: on a side note, it might be better to rely on css to do responsiveness.

Comment: maybe you haven't put an specific width to your div

Answer (score 0):

add ); to your script end.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("width : "+$(".div").innerWidth());
});
```

```css
.div{width:800px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">dghgdh</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var select = $('div');

    console.log('innerWidth: ' + select.innerWidth(), 'innerHeight: ' + select.innerHeight());

    console.log('clientWidth: ' + select[0].clientWidth, 'clientHeight: ' + select[0].clientHeight);

    console.log('offsetWidth: ' + select[0].offsetWidth, 'offsetHeight: ' + select[0].offsetHeight);
    console.log('width: ' + select.width(), 'height: ' + select.width());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is scroll bar.You can try it

**window.innerWidth**: with scrollbar

**$(window).width()**: without scrollbar